# How to manually create a Word.RangeCollection and add ranges to it?

Tags: office-js, word-addins

In Word add-in API, Word.RangeCollection has the load() function while an array of Word.Range doesn't. Is there a way to manually create a collection and add ranges to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to "`new`" most objects in the Office JS library. You should loop through the array of Range objects and call the Range.load method on each one. (Note, the `context.sync` should be *after* the loop, not inside it.)